# Updating to last version of the monodroid and now the solution not builds

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin

Today I update my monodroid to the its last version. Before this my solution works fine but no I got this errors:

```
 MyProjectPath\Classes\Presentation Layer\Class Override\ImageLoaderListener.cs(15,15): Error CS0012: The type 'Java.Lang.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c4c4237547e4b6cd'. (CS0012) (RPLAndroidApp)
```

and also this:

```
MyProjectPath\Class Override\ImageLoaderListener.cs(15,15): Error CS0012: The type 'Android.Runtime.IJavaObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c4c4237547e4b6cd'. (CS0012) (RPLAndroidApp)
```

I tried to recompile my java library that I build by 'JavaBindingLibraryProject' and add them again to project but When I build them I get many errors.

I'm confused what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuild all your projects with the new version of Mono for Android. You have to do this because of the [changes in Assembly strongnames.](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1476/changes-to-assembly-strongnames-in-xamarin-android-4-6-0)

Comment: How can I do this? I just rebuild solution but it not working. What other jobs should I do?